# Python Pandas Dataframe: Take next smaller value based on separate column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a transaction table. for 1 Date, number of records can be present for 1 transaction ID.

I want to add a new column in same df so that it can pull the date previous to the date of concerned row for each transaction ID.

If there is no previous date transaction, new column should be blank. if for previous date there are more than 1 records, value of first record for that date should be populated in above records.

In excel, using the combination of Match and Index, I populated the values however I am new to python and struggling to get this done in correct way.

I was thinking if self join can be used (Transaction ID can be the key and in where condition `Transaction_Date` of `t2 < Transaction_Date of t1`) or if there is something more efficient way in Python.

Data is sorted by Transaction ID and Transaction date (descending order).

**Input Data:**

```
Transaction_ID  Transaction_Date  Invoice
1001            3/27/2020         10,000 
1001            3/27/2020         10,000 
1001            3/27/2020         10,000 
1002            1/23/2020         127,000 
1002            10/30/2019        117,000 
1003            3/26/2020         291,000 
1003            3/24/2020         292,000 
1003            1/15/2020         290,000 
1003            12/30/2019        292,000 
1003            10/21/2019        189,000 
1003            10/21/2019        189,000 
1004            2/17/2020         1,261,500 
1004            2/14/2020         1,262,000 
1004            1/14/2020         1,552,000 
1004            1/14/2020         1,452,000 
1004            12/14/2019        1,000,000 
1004            11/4/2019         2,392,000 
1004            11/4/2019         2,792,000
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Transaction_ID  Transaction_Date  Invoice    Previous_Transaction_Date  Previous_Invoice_amount
1001            3/27/2020         10,000           
1001            3/27/2020         10,000           
1001            3/27/2020         10,000           
1002            1/23/2020         127,000    10/30/2019                 117,000 
1002            10/30/2019        117,000          
1003            3/26/2020         291,000    3/24/2020                  292,000 
1003            3/24/2020         292,000    1/15/2020                  290,000 
1003            1/15/2020         290,000    12/30/2019                 292,000 
1003            12/30/2019        292,000    10/21/2019                 189,000 
1003            10/21/2019        189,000          
1003            10/21/2019        189,000          
1004            2/17/2020         1,261,500  2/14/2020                  1,262,000 
1004            2/14/2020         1,262,000  1/14/2020                  1,552,000 
1004            1/14/2020         1,552,000  12/14/2019                 1,000,000 
1004            1/14/2020         1,452,000  12/14/2019                 1,000,000 
1004            12/14/2019        1,000,000  11/4/2019                  2,392,000 
1004            11/4/2019         2,392,000  9/10/2020                  900,050 
1004            11/4/2019         2,792,000  9/10/2020                  900,050
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lots of `.shift` logic with `np.where`, `.ne` and `.eq`, which will get the job done.

```
df1 = df.copy()
#Main Logic
df1['Previous_Transaction_Date'] = np.where(((df1['Transaction_Date'].ne(df1['Transaction_Date'].shift(1))) |
                                                 (df1['Transaction_Date'].ne(df1['Transaction_Date'].shift(-1)))) &
                                                  (df1['Transaction_ID'].eq(df1['Transaction_ID'].shift(-1))),
                                                 df1['Transaction_Date'].shift(-1), '')
df1['Previous_Invoice_amount'] = np.where(((df1['Transaction_Date'].ne(df1['Transaction_Date'].shift(1))) |
                                                 (df1['Transaction_Date'].ne(df1['Transaction_Date'].shift(-1)))) &
                                                  (df1['Transaction_ID'].eq(df1['Transaction_ID'].shift(-1))),
                                                 df1['Invoice'].shift(-1), '')
#Supplementary logic to get rest of cells.
df1['Previous_Transaction_Date'] = np.where(df1['Previous_Transaction_Date'] == df1['Transaction_Date'],
                                            df1['Previous_Transaction_Date'].shift(-1), df1['Previous_Transaction_Date'])
df1['Previous_Invoice_amount'] = np.where(df1['Previous_Transaction_Date'] == '',
                                          '', df1['Previous_Invoice_amount'])
df1['Previous_Invoice_amount'] = np.where(((df1['Transaction_ID'].eq(df1['Transaction_ID'].shift(-1))) &
                                          (df1['Transaction_Date'].eq(df1['Transaction_Date'].shift(-1)))),
                                          df1['Previous_Invoice_amount'].shift(-1),df1['Previous_Invoice_amount'])
df1
```

Keep in mind that the highest count of Transaction_Date is two, except for in the first 3 rows. If you have a count of three or higher of Transaction_Date in your larger dataset, then you may not get the results that you are expecting.